# PHP passing percentage as argument

Tags: php, arguments, percentage

I wanted to implement a PHP function to mimic how [CSS handles RGB](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#color-units). In CSS, a RGB color can be specified using percentages `rgb(50%, 50%, 50%)`. However, if I have this PHP function:

```
function rgb($r, $g, $b) {
    ...
}
```

and call it using percentages it causes a parse error because PHP uses the percent sign (`%`) for modular division.

Is there anyway to pass percentages as arguments or do I have to pass the values another way (strings, decimals, etc.)?

**Edit**

In CSS RGB values can be specified in two ways. Either through integers ranging from 0 to 255 or percentages from 0% to 100%. Therefore, percentages could not be integers because `rgb(50, 50, 50)` could mean red, green, and blue values of 50 (out of 255) or 50%.

Comment: i see no reason to pass percentage sign

Comment: Pass a string if you really need the sign, you're just complicating things TBH...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string "50%" is a very human centric expression. You have to handle it as a string, not as a mathematical term. So:

```
function rgb("50%", "50%", "50%") {
    ...
}
```

Or, in a more flexible way:

```
$r = "50%";
$g = "50%";
$b = "50%";
function rgb( $r, $g, $b ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

However i see no reason to pass percentage sign but you can  pass it like a string  if you don't want to perform mathematical operation

```
rgb('50%', '50%', '50%')
```

or use like

```
function rgb($r, $g, $b) {
   echo $r.'%';
}
```